# Image 404 not found on Heroku Sinatra site

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

I'm trying to deploy a simple Sinatra app on Heroku, and for some reason when I push to Heroku, the site can't find an image (I've tried png and jpg) in public/images. It finds all the other assets in the public folder, but doesn't want to load the image. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to show us some code. Even better: push your repository to Github and link to it here, if possible.

Comment: there is no good reason for that. does it give a 404?

Comment: Yeah, it gives a 404. Here's the git repo: git@github.com:bschreck/calendarApp.git

Comment: I don't know what I did but now it's working.

Comment: There is no `public/images` dir in that repo. Have you added and committed your image files?